# Eclipse not honoring runtime VM memory options?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to run an algorithm that requires a few hundred megabytes of memory within eclipse, and I've specified VM arguments -Xmx512m, but I can't get past some arbitrary memory limit which seems to decrease as I continually try to run my programs. Physical memory is fine...what could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse takes VM arguments, but those are for the Eclipse platform itself, you need to modify the applications *Launch Configuration* to ensure it has enough memory.

When you run a program within Eclipse it creates a new Launch Configuration with default parameters. You can modify those parameters by selecting **Run**->**Run Configurations..** (or **Debug**->**Debug Configurations...**), then select the relevant configuration. If it is a Java main app, the configuration will be under **Java Application**, probably with the name of the class or project you selected when you first ran it.

Select the launch configuration, then the **Arguments** tab, then enter the relevant JVM arguments (i.e -Xmx512m) in the **VM arguments** pane. You can also enter **Program arguments** to pass to the main method if you wish.

[image: launch configuration screenshot]
<sub>(source: [modumind.com](https://www.modumind.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/launch-arguments-1.png))</sub>

Update: another parameter to try passing is `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`, if your algorithm is creating lots of method and/or class objects (which sounds like it is the case).

Comment: I've added another property for you to try.

Comment: I was indeed creating lots of class objects.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the arguments -Xms  too.  Be sure that the argument is specify to your Run mode ( Run  / debug).

If you still have some problem, you can use a profiler to see what happen in memory, or just logging the Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()  can help.

Comment: I've tried -Xms, but that still didn't help. I really hope Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() isn't necessary, but thanks for the tip regardless.

Answer (score -1):

You should ensure that you are specifying the arguments for your test application in the Run Dialog, and not in arguments to Eclipse itself.